# How to generate a PDF output from a template PDF using something other than iText?

Tags: java, scala, itext, pdfbox

I'm working on a small Scala/Java prototype where I have several PDF templates i.e. they have text and image placeholders and the placeholders should be replaced with some content. Some sections are also multiple i.e. the actual number of occurrences or repetitions depends on the input. Then finally I need to generate and append an extra PDF page.

I'm aware that these use-cases can be covered using iText. My question is whether I can use an alternative solution for this (and how to do it). I'd prefer to avoid commercial solutions for the time being.

UPDATE: I'd like my PDF templates to be created by professional designers. They will know where the placeholders will be but should have full control on the design aspects. This requirement discards solutions based solely on XML inputs or others where the PDF is created fully programmatically.

Comment: There is an older iText version (2?) that was released under LGPL not AGPL 3 if that matters.

Comment: You may find interesting to look at http://go.applidok.com , having API to merge data with PDF template from many languages, including Scala ( http://play-demo.applidok.com ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jasper](http://community.jaspersoft.com/download) - It's sofrware designed for crating dynamic reports connected with database inputs, but I think it can be utilized in the way you want. Has a graphical designer (either iReport or JaspersoftStudio based on your preferences), supports passing multiple variables with content or even images. Long static formatted texts may be a problem, but you will have to judge that for yourself.

[JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) + [JODConverter](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) - those two tools will allow your designers to work in pure ODT (OpenOffice format) files putting in dynamic data as variables that you will be able to substitute to your hearts desires from your Java code and print the output in PDF format. More than that, thanks to [Java UNO](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html) API you can seize full control over the way your template looks and behaves if your inserted texts are really complex (though admittedly it's not intuitive to use).